# Issues Coming Back From Suspend?

Tags: suspend, hp, 17.04

I have a HP Pavilion DV7T-1000. I recently installed Kubuntu 17.04 on it, and even on a fresh install a strange problem occurs. When the computer comes back from a suspend, the login screen does not load, and occasionally the screen flickers erratically (This is somewhat rare though). Usually the login screen does not display. This requires a restart of the system which is a pain. Do any techno-wizards/witches know of any terminal spells or setting rituals I can perform to solve this problem? I can provide more information, including a video if needed.

The hardware is configured in a FakeRAID configuration. Although I don't know of what type. I think this is leading to the suspend issue, although I'm not 100% sure. I've read the FakeRAID how to page, but I didn't find it very helpful, and it appears badly dated. If you have any diagnostics you would like me to run, I'm more than happy to do them, and make edits to the question.

Edit 0: I tried the TuxonIce approach, but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is the third or fourth time the question has been asked. It appears to be a bug in the display blanking of the window manager code. As Ubuntu is gutting all that for the future it probably won't be fixed.

My solution to the problem (vanilla Ubuntu 17.04) has been to go into settings and disable all screen blanking/screensavers functions. then to set the system to directly go into suspend or to use the actual Power button and OSD to go directly to suspend. that seemed to get it working for me so the system isn't just fully awake all the time. it still seems buggy if I try to immediately wake it back up, but most of the time it's suspended for 15-30 minutes and will wake up correctly.

Comment: Hmm, are you saying that future versions won't have this problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need more space for your swap or upgrade your RAM. A good practice is having your swap area twice as much as your RAM